# How to call an array by button

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and I want to call the array by button, Also I wanted it keep calling the array every time when I click on button. Please correct the array if it has any issue.

my array is :

```
array (

"name" => __('name1','vbegy'),
"id" => $this->shortname."_menu_1",
"desc" => __('name2)','vbegy'),
"type" =>  "text",
"std" => __('name3','vbegy'),

),

array (

"name" => __('name4','vbegy'),
"id" => $this->shortname."_menu_1_url",
"desc" => __('name5)','vbegy'),
"type" =>  "text",

),
```

Comment: Can you add a language tag?

Comment: Where's your button?

Comment: I'm new at PHP code so I don't have a button code

Comment: Can you add a language tag? php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think first thing you should do is to learn how to use HTML forms/buttons and use PHP to process them. Below is a simple form example.

In your HTML file, add

```
<form method="post" action="your-php-file.php">
<input type="text" name="text-name" value="">
<input type="submit" name="button-name" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your PHP file (your-php-file.php), add

```
    $array1 = array(
        "name" => array('name1' => 'vbegy'),
        "id" => $this->shortname."_menu_1",
        "desc" => array('name2' => 'vbegy'),
        "type" =>  "text",
        "std" => array('name3','vbegy')
    );

    $array2 = array (
        "name" => array('name4' => 'vbegy'),
        "id" => $this->shortname."_menu_1_url",
        "desc" => array('name5' => 'vbegy'),
        "type" =>  "text"
    );

    if (isset($_POST['button-name'])) {
        //use php to process your array data as you want
        echo $array1['name']['name1']; //print vbegy
        echo $array1['type']; //print text
        echo $array2['desc']['name5']; //print vbegy

        $std = $array1['std']['name3'];
        echo $std; //print vbegy

        echo "You clicked submit button!";
    }
```

For detailed explanation, please use following links.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried to use this code, but as i said i'm new in coding, so can you make for me the code with the array that i have post

Comment: Your question is not clear enough for me to give you a clear answer. What exactly do you want to do with that array data?
More about PHP arrays, follow http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: with the array that i post, when i press on the button it should call the array. Also when i press again on the button it should call the array again. so whenever i press on the button it should call the array.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm giving you a hard time with me. here a image [link](http://s14.postimg.org/9esiwugrl/Untitled.png) what i want to do is when i press on add more it should add for me add your header menu and add the URL. forget about my array. can you make for me a code that do this job.

Comment: I forget to say that i'm trying to do this in WordPress Script.

Comment: Well in that case, I think you gonna have to learn lots of stuff about both PHP and Wordpress. Try to find and follow some tutorials online. If my answer is useful, please accept it as the answer for your question. Thanks.

Comment: About your image, I think something like jQuery will be useful.

Comment: I tried every thing but it's not working. I tried by php and html and jquery and java all of them not working.